# How do I write this PowerShell query more efficiently?

Tags: powershell

I am looking to see what the cleaner way of writing this one liner would be.

```
Get-AdGroup -Filter * -Properties Name,Description,whenCreated,whenChanged,ObjectClass,GroupCategory,GroupScope,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName |
    Sort-Object Name |
    Select-Object Name,Description,whenCreated,whenChanged,ObjectClass,GroupCategory,GroupScope,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName |
    Select *,@{Name="Members";Expression={Get-ADGroupMember $_.Name | %{$_.SamAccountName+';'}}} |
    Export-Csv -Path .\Group.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

And assign the property names to a variable so they are written out in full twice, and combine `Select-Object` and `select` together:

```
$properties = "Name,Description,whenCreated,whenChanged,ObjectClass,GroupCategory,GroupScope,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName";
Get-AdGroup -filter * -properties $properties |
    Select-Object $properties,@{Name="Members";Expression={Get-ADGroupMember $_.Name | %{$_.SamAccountName+';'}}} |
    Sort-Object Name |
    Export-Csv -Path .\Group.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note: It's a one liner command but I've spaced it out for readability.

Comment: Should be an array not a string, oops, try: `$properties = @("Name","Description","whenCreated","whenChanged","ObjectClass","GroupCategory","GroupScope","SamAccountName","DistinguishedName");`